# open text files with my ios app

Tags: ios

I am trying to register my app as being able to open text files.  Based on some digging, below is what I tried and while it compiled, it didnt work.  When I go into dropbox and try to launch a txt file, I get 'No installed apps support opening this file'.  What do I need to do to make my app show up for any txt file?

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>Text File</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Viewer</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
<array>
<string>txt</string>
<string>TXT</string>
</array>
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
<string>Alternate</string>
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
<array>
<string>public.txt</string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My app imports TXT files, too.
Change your Info.plist:

- Change public.txt in the listing above to com.myapp.txt (or whatever you want)
- After the last `</array>` of your listing above add:

  ```
  <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
  <array>
  <dict>
      <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
      <array>
          <string>public.text</string>
      </array>
      <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
      <string>Plain Text Document</string>
      <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
      <string>com.myapp.txt</string>
      <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
      <dict>
          <key>public.filename-extension</key>
          <string>txt</string>
          <key>public.mime-type</key>
          <string>text/plain</string>
      </dict>
  </dict>
  </array>
  ```

You may replace com.myapp.txt with whatever identifier you want.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Just to clarify are you saying to replace mine with yours or keep mine + mod and add yours?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not clear on the mods to mine.  A bit new to iOS development.

Comment: Added some explanations in my answer.

Comment: should the identifier by my app id?  Appreciate the help.

Comment: No, you could choose anything conforming the reverse-DNS format. (com.xx.xx or net.xx.xx and so on)

Comment: ok, but I did throw my app ID in and it worked so at least it is showing up but will change as per your suggestion.  Thanks for the guidance, my app now takes in txt files.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer updated for iOS 11 and Xcode 9**

If the document type you are adding is not a custom document type, you don't have to "register your app" because the standard types are already know by iOS (this is the case of text files).

Just select the target in your project and enter the text file type in the **Document Types** section:

[image]

For more info, please see the "Adding A Document Type" section of this Apple's document: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html