# Open an emailed text file with my swift2 iOS app

Tags: ios, swift2, plist, identifier, open-with

I have read this: [open text files with my ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586477/open-text-files-with-my-ios-app) and it's great in the fact that it allows me to see my app as one of the options to open it with and when selecting my app it opens my app but that's it. There are two problems:

First of all, while "opening with" for example Google drive says "Copy to Drive", while mine says "Copy to (null)" when I want it to say "Copy to HotSpotRIS". How can I do this? At least the app icon shows up. If it helps, my overall bundle identifier for my entire project is www.epicode.com.HotSpotRIS. Here are three pictures showing you what I am specifically talking about where the first picture is showing you the emailed txt, second is the user holding down on the txt file, and the third is the "open with" menu that pops up from this with my app reading "Copy to (null)":

[image][image][image]

Second of all, I know how to read and write text files and how to navigate the iOS file system but how do I connect my code to the .plist file in order to read the emailed txt file? I am guessing there needs to be some identifier that I can then use to call to obtain the txt data. Here is my info.plist file so far with the last bit of the file being the code I got from [open text files with my ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586477/open-text-files-with-my-ios-app):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>NSLocationWhenInUseUsage</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Text File</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>txt</string>
                <string>TXT</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>www.epicode.com.HotSpotRIS.txt</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.text</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Plain Text Document</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>www.epicode.com.HotSpotRIS.txt</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>txt</string>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>text/plain</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thank you in advance!